# Cloudformation Resource for a Cross Region S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudformation

I know this is somewhat a duplicate of  [Cross Region S3 bucket policy](https://serverfault.com/questions/452387/cross-region-s3-bucket-policy) but I don't have enough rep to comment and the answer wasn't detailed enough.

I would like to allow EC2 servers based in us-east-1 to read content from a bucket in us-west-2.

Every time I try I get a "The Bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint"

Referencing the endpoints: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

I'm trying to figure out the actual format for the Resource, or how to specify the endpoint inside the cloudformation document. RE:

"Resource": { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn: aws: s3: : : ", { "Ref": "ChefBucket" }, "/*" ]] },

I've tried specifying it as:

bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
s3.amazonaws.com/bucket
even:
bucket.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (which isn't listed but s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com does exist)

I either get a "no such bucket" error or the error above. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a duplicate as I mentioned at the top of the question, but the answer didn't provide enough detail and I don't have the reputation points to comment on it.

Comment: Then wait until you have enough rep.

Comment: It's not a duplicate really. The original post was only asking if it was possible. I'm asking about a specific implementation detail.